# Correct usage of regex lookahead in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that is supposed to list some dollar amounts and looks like this:

```
4000.05 . 5.200000000 300.650000 2000 .
```

It is ultimately supposed to look like this:

```
4000.05 5200000000 300650000 2000
```

with all non-decimal periods removed.  I am attempting to use this regex to remove all periods that are not followed by two numbers and then a non-numeric character:

```
re.sub(".(?!([0-9])?!([0-9])?=([0-9]))","",f)
```

but this ends up emptying the entire string.  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What makes something a non-decimal period? I.e. why is the period in `300.650000` removed. That is a perfectly valid decimal number...

Comment: What should happen to the string `'12.34.56'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, a `dot` is a meta-character in regex, that matches any character. You need to escape it. Or put in a character class, where meta-characters don't have any special meaning. Of course you need to escape the closing brackets `]`, which will otherwise be taken as the end of character class.

Secondly your negative look-ahead is flawed.

Try something like this:

```
re.sub(r'[.](?![0-9]{2}\W)',"",s)
```

Comment: I've found that when using the `re` module it's a good policy to use raw strings: `re.sub(r'...', '', s)`.

Comment: Did you mean `\b` rather than `\W`?

Comment: It might be simpler in this case just to escape the dot (another good reason to use raw strings).

Comment: @NullUserException. Actually I meant flawed. ;)

Comment: *"Or put in a character class, where meta-characters don't have any special meaning."* Where **some** meta characters don't have any special meaning.

Comment: @lmjohns3. Yeah, but that's out of my own practice. I mostly prefer character classes than escaping.

Comment: @NullUserException. Nope. None of them have special meaning. Just the hyphen has, when used in the middle. Well, but that's not a meta-character outside.

Comment: @RohitJain Other ones I can immediately think of is the bracket and the backslash `\]`. Also escaping and character classes work differently, ie: `\.\?` and `[.?]` don't mean the same thing. You have to be careful there and understand what you're doing.

Comment: @RohitJain And oh yes, the caret (`[^a-z]`)

Comment: @RohitJain that's why I thought just escaping the dot would be simpler. Simpler to explain, if nothing else. :)

Comment: @NullUserException. `^` also has special meaning when used at the beginning of a character class. Outside it's not. `[ab^c]` will match `^`, AFAIK.

Comment: @lmjohns3. I'll do it next time. :)

Comment: @RohitJain Yes, you can strategically place the caret and hyphen in character classes so they lose their special meaning.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this.

```
string = '4000.05 . 5.200000000 300.650000 2000 .'
print re.sub(r'[.](?![0-9]{2}\D)', '', string)
```

The regular expression:

```
[.]                      any character of: '.'
  (?!                    look ahead to see if there is not:
    [0-9]{2}             any character of: '0' to '9' (2 times)
            \D           match non-digits (all but 0-9)
  )                      end of look-ahead
```

Comment: You missed the closing `]` after `0-9`.